# bash run function with different user

Tags: bash, sudo

Would be possible to run a custom bash function with different priviledges?

```
#!/bin/bash
function RunStefano() {
     while [ 1 ]; do
         echo "Ciao, ´/usr/bin/whoami´"
         sleep 10;
     done &
}
export -f RunStefano;
echo "Welcome, ´/usr/bin/whoami´"
sudo -u stefano -c "RunStefano"
```

If I run this script with 'root' user, I want to receive as output:

```
Welcome, root
Ciao, stefano
    (...)
Ciao, stefano
```

Would it be possibile?

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Trying shows that you can't do it *that way*. It doesn't show that you can't *somehow* run a single function as another user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that, at least not directly. (But see [Richard Fletcher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23733747/827263).)

Each *process* runs under a particular user account. By default, that's the same account as the process that invoked it. `sudo` lets a process running under one account launch another process that runs under a different account.

When you invoke a shell function, it doesn't launch a new process. With some modifications, your script should give you something like:

```
sudo: RunStefano: command not found
```

In the new process created by `sudo`, there is no `RunStefano` command; the function is local to the process running the script.

You need to isolate the function into a separate executable script; you can then invoke that script via `sudo`.

Incidentally, you also need to change the apostrophes around `/usr/bin/whoami` to backticks:

```
echo "Ciao, `/usr/bin/whoami`"
```

And you should read the documentation for the `sudo` command; it doesn't have a `-c` option.

Comment: Ciao Keith. Thanks for your kindly answer. I'll procede as you're suggesting! Thanks again!

Comment: As @RichardFletcher said, this is possible. See the other post

Comment: In theory bash could have builtin that would create a subshell, then call `setuid` after forking, and before evaluating the subshell code (for ex calling a function). Which would be a lot more reliable than using functions exported in environment variables. But afaik, bash doesn't have such a mechanism.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, this is possible

```
#!/bin/bash
function1(){
   echo `whoami` 
}
export -f function1
su username -c "bash -c function1"
exit 0
```

Comment: Interesting solution. This exports the function definition as text to an environment variable (in the current version of bash it's named `BASH_FUNC_function1%%`). Note that the function won't have visibility to other things defined in the script, as it would if it were called directly.

Comment: I'll note that you could get the same functionality by putting `function1` in a separate script, and invoking that script using `su`.